# Double click datagrid and paste to database record

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, reportviewer

I want to double click a row in my datagrid and to transfer that data to my database, which then goes on to open a report based on that data just transferred.

````
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        End If
        'Dim PtwNoData As String = String.Empty

        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim Command As SqlCommand
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim IdLast As Integer
        Dim PTWNo As String
        Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
        connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\IzzyM\Desktop\Developer\BIG\Permit Plus\Permit Plus\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim GuiD As String

        'GuiD = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows("GUID").Selected.

        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into PTWData * values ('" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(). & "')"
            Command = New SqlCommand(Query, connection)
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

            connection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Dispose()
        End Try
        'Form4.Dispose()
        Dim f As New Form4()
        f.TopMost = True
        f.Show()
        'Form4.Show()
    End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wanting to add string values there, but the selected rows is a complicated object.  It contains the resulting rows and each column within (along with many, many properties).

See below, where "ColumnNameIDK" is only one and you may have many to consider.  This query will ultimately be a lot of inserts.  (For safety sake, we may want to convert this to a parameterized query down the road)

...

```
Dim Query As String
Dim rows As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = MyDataGridView.SelectedRows


for each row in Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows()
   Dim myRow As DataRow = (TryCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)).Row
    query &= "insert into PTWData * values ('" & myRow("ColumnNameIDK")& "');"
    'this query appended on each pass   
next
Command = New SqlCommand(Query, connection)
Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, however thi throws up the following error:

"Unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow' to type 'system.data.datarow'.

Comment: Ah I had this before, since they're 2 different objects, you have to do a conversion to treat it as your typical Datatable Datarow.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks this saved me from throwing myself off a bridge tonight! much appreciated